# How to get results as List<Map<String, Object>> using CriteriaQuery?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have big table with around 50 columns and client will decide which are the columns he wants. based on that I need to give the data.

Using javax.persistence.Query, I am able to select specific columns as below:

```
String query = "Select new map (dataId as dataId, dataNumber as dataNumber) From Data";
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(10);
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = q.getResultList();
```

I would like to implement same with CriteriaQuery and I tried like below:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Data> cQuery = cb.createQuery(Data.class);
Root<Data> c = cQuery.from(Data.class);
cQuery.multiselect(c.get("dataId"), c.get("dataName"));
List<Data> t = entityManager.createQuery(cQuery).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
```

For above code, its expecting constructor of "Data(dataId, dataName)".

I want a way to query specific fields from a table using CriteriaQuery without writing constructor for selected fields.
Please help me with this.

Comment: You can't. End of. Massage the data into that form in Java

Comment: @DN1 Sorry I didnt get you. "Massage the data into that form in Java"

Comment: @DN1 so you mean to say that I need to go with the approach of javax.persistence.Query which was described above ?

Comment: The JPQL you post makes no sense; you say there is a constructor in class "map" taking 2 arguments. There isn't (assuming you mean java.util.Map)

Comment: @DN1 No constructor written for the JPQL. we just need to specify "new map(<specific fields here>)". it will give us the List<Map<String, Object>>. Example in JSON: [
        {
            "dataId": 11674217,
            "dataNumber": "1004436"
        },
        {
            "dataId": 11674218,
            "dataNumber": "1004437"
        }
]

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about now. Suggest that you revise your question incorporating all comments and start again

Answer (score 0):

As told in [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause), dynamic instantion with `map` as in this case, and with `list`as well, are additional features in HQL and not part of the JPQL.

Criteria API does not provide means for constructing such a select.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is possible using plain JPA with [`Tuple`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html).

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cQuery = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Data> c = cQuery.from(Data.class);
cQuery.multiselect(c.get("dataId"), c.get("dataName"));
List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(cQuery).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();

List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = resultList
   .stream()
   .map(tuple -> tuple.getElements()
                      .stream()
                      .map(element -> Map.entry(element.getAlias(), tuple.get(element.getAlias())))
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you should be able to pass the fields you like in the `multiselect()`.

You have to be a bit careful when you have joins and aggregates or more complex queries, it doesn't always work.